# Deleting Old LVMS

Tags: lvm

I'm using RHEL9 on VMWare and I was following a RHEL course and creating LVM's and extending them in my VMWare. I removed the extra disks in VMWare, confirmed that they were gone via lsblk, added new disks and then redid the exercises in my course. I noticed that I'm getting messages regarding my old disks when I run pvs, lvs, or vgs. Does anyone know how I can get rid of them? Here's my output and please let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

```
[root@server1 ~]# pvs
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.694d23db39adb5e5000c296f16276b9b PVID UGehCcHnR5Ud32dgjIJ52SGfzW13ht1M last seen on /dev/nvme0n3p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.725f1dc391decc8a000c2968de6d8e2e PVID XF9w40zG2eklRw87ly57qzWapfuJI7ss last seen on /dev/nvme0n5p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.725f1dc391decc8a000c2968de6d8e2e PVID rQ1AhQVfqSYOd7TQ7mrxRMIxyHv0ZYRv last seen on /dev/nvme0n5p2 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.1980655febb3c392000c29691e59af71 PVID 9lHXG7HskeRNQ05eFJOBCNg68benZ33K last seen on /dev/nvme0n7p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.1980655febb3c392000c29691e59af71 PVID Orz06yF3Q5ODYDSbsm3OTVmwszWordiq last seen on /dev/nvme0n7p2 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.312757f5a371ce78000c296dd0907eb0 PVID TnGzeNPVwiUODoKU8irccjggtPi4eJcQ last seen on /dev/nvme0n8p1 not found.
  PV             VG      Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   
  /dev/nvme0n1p2 rhel    lvm2 a--    11.00g    4.00m
  /dev/nvme0n3p1 vgdata  lvm2 a--     1.99g 1016.00m
  /dev/nvme0n4p1 vgfiles lvm2 a--  1020.00m       0 
  /dev/nvme0n4p2 vgfiles lvm2 a--  1020.00m  508.00m
[root@server1 ~]# lvs
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.694d23db39adb5e5000c296f16276b9b PVID UGehCcHnR5Ud32dgjIJ52SGfzW13ht1M last seen on /dev/nvme0n3p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.725f1dc391decc8a000c2968de6d8e2e PVID XF9w40zG2eklRw87ly57qzWapfuJI7ss last seen on /dev/nvme0n5p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.725f1dc391decc8a000c2968de6d8e2e PVID rQ1AhQVfqSYOd7TQ7mrxRMIxyHv0ZYRv last seen on /dev/nvme0n5p2 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.1980655febb3c392000c29691e59af71 PVID 9lHXG7HskeRNQ05eFJOBCNg68benZ33K last seen on /dev/nvme0n7p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.1980655febb3c392000c29691e59af71 PVID Orz06yF3Q5ODYDSbsm3OTVmwszWordiq last seen on /dev/nvme0n7p2 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.312757f5a371ce78000c296dd0907eb0 PVID TnGzeNPVwiUODoKU8irccjggtPi4eJcQ last seen on /dev/nvme0n8p1 not found.
  LV      VG      Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root    rhel    -wi-ao---- 10.00g                                                    
  swap    rhel    -wi-ao----  1.00g                                                    
  lvdata  vgdata  -wi-ao----  1.00g                                                    
  lvfiles vgfiles -wi-ao---- <1.50g                                                    
[root@server1 ~]# vgs
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.694d23db39adb5e5000c296f16276b9b PVID UGehCcHnR5Ud32dgjIJ52SGfzW13ht1M last seen on /dev/nvme0n3p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.725f1dc391decc8a000c2968de6d8e2e PVID XF9w40zG2eklRw87ly57qzWapfuJI7ss last seen on /dev/nvme0n5p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.725f1dc391decc8a000c2968de6d8e2e PVID rQ1AhQVfqSYOd7TQ7mrxRMIxyHv0ZYRv last seen on /dev/nvme0n5p2 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.1980655febb3c392000c29691e59af71 PVID 9lHXG7HskeRNQ05eFJOBCNg68benZ33K last seen on /dev/nvme0n7p1 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.1980655febb3c392000c29691e59af71 PVID Orz06yF3Q5ODYDSbsm3OTVmwszWordiq last seen on /dev/nvme0n7p2 not found.
  Devices file sys_wwid eui.312757f5a371ce78000c296dd0907eb0 PVID TnGzeNPVwiUODoKU8irccjggtPi4eJcQ last seen on /dev/nvme0n8p1 not found.
  VG      #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree   
  rhel      1   2   0 wz--n- 11.00g    4.00m
  vgdata    1   1   0 wz--n-  1.99g 1016.00m
  vgfiles   2   1   0 wz--n-  1.99g  508.00m
```

Comment: Sorry - the format didn't turn out the way I wanted. Basically, I'm getting this error regarding my previous disks:  Devices file sys_wwid eui.694d23db39adb5e5000c296f16276b9b PVID UGehCcHnR5Ud32dgjIJ52SGfzW13ht1M last seen on /dev/nvme0n3p1 not found.

Comment: is it this issue? https://serverfault.com/questions/1093110/linux-lvm-pvid-last-seen-on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newly created LVM PVs are now added to the `/etc/lvm/devices/system.devices` config file and LVM tries to scan all devices listed here. Normally `pvremove` will remove the entry from the file but because you removed the disks directly from your VM without running `pvremove` first, the disks were not removed from the config file and LVM is still trying to use the PVs. You need to remove the missing PVs using

```
lvmdevices --delpvid UGehCcHnR5Ud32dgjIJ52SGfzW13ht1M
```

(repeat for all missing PVs). You can also manually remove them from the file.

Comment: Vojtech - Thanks! I'm getting errors when I run the command:  [root@server1 ~]# lvmdevices --deviceidtype sys_wwid --deldev eui.694d23db39adb5e5000c296f16276b9b
  Command does not accept option: --deviceidtype sys_wwid.   . Any ideas? I checked man pages for lvmdevices but don't see the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I #'d them out in /etc/lvm/devices/system.devices as a test and ran lvs and they're not showing so that solves my issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: Looks like the `--deviceidtype` is not available on RHEL 9, I was testing this on CentOS 9 Stream which has newer version of LVM that RHEL 9.0. I've updated the answer to use the `--delpvid` option instead.

Comment: Vojtech - thanks so much my friend! That command worked. Thanks and I learned so much on this problem. Glad I had it. I have CentOS 9 on a VM and I'll start to play around with it too.